# Why not, despite applying css overflow:hidden?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I try to make sure that if the horizontal length is long on this homepage, everything is printed out, otherwise the text element does not appear inside.
However, as in the attached image, if the horizontal length is reduced, the icon on the right is off the box.
Overflow:hidden in div with text, but the icon comes out before the text is omitted.
What should I do?

```
<style>
#headerText{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    color:\#ffffff;
    font-size: 28pt;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#HeadLogo{
    float: right;
    overflow: inherit;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image : url('../../../image/cbu_simple_logo.png');
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    background-size : cover;
}

</style>
```

[full page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyau2.png)
[short page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1JBg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does #HeaderText refer to the div that contains the #HeadLogo?

the hidden overflow works like this:

```css
div.myHiddenOverFlow {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border:solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<h2>overflow: hidden:</h2>
<div class="myHiddenOverFlow">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>
```

Comment: #HeaderText don't refer to the div that contains the #HeadLogo.
the html works like this:
```
    <header>
 <div id="headerText">AAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
 <div id=HeadLogo>
  <img ~~ />
 </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: ok, so add the "overflow:hidden" to the header style